# How to amplify a collection of sound files

Tags: editing, batch-processing

I have up to 200 audio files which are really short (2,3 seconds maximum) but they need to be amplified.

1) Is there a fast way of amplification for a playlist of sounds?

also...

2)Is there a best/automatic way for amplification of sounds at maximum possible?

3) I've tried with audacity, but I don't know how to set the amplification factor in order to obtain a maximum amplification and no bad effects.

If no automatic playlist amplify way is possible I’ll do it manually, but I don’t know how the handle problem 3.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean you want to edit each file to increase it's volume, or you just want to play them all back at high volume?

If the latter, just set the volume in your playback tool of choice to its maximum and play the entire list.

If however you want to increase the volume of each file you can use Audacity's normalisation function:

- Go to File > Edit Chains
- Add Normalize
- Insert Normalization
- Then go to File > Normalise > Apply to Files

This will increase the volume of each one as high as it can.

Comment: If you can (I think Audacity lets you do this) normalize to -1dBFS,   to avoid [intersample distortion](http://www.hometracked.com/2007/11/08/prevent-intersample-peaks/).

Comment: If I remember, I think that is the default (It has been a while)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my answer on [matching the volume across multiple files](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/3772/2197).

**Adobe Audition** has a '**Match Volume**' feature which can batch process the volume of files as well as the ability to set up custom actions (or favourites).

Audition isnt free, but its a decent program and available on Windows and OSX. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

use sox and create a simple batch file to apply a gain change or normalization to every single file. Sox is your friend.